# Translating Data using Apex Triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, developer, database

I am trying to import a database that have numbers in the picklist value. (1,2,3,4,5..etc)

However, in the user-end, they should see different set of values, for example (

1.-> Partner
   2.->LLC
   3.->Other

So I want an apex trigger saying

IF field value is 1; then replace it to Partner
IF field value is 2; then replace it to LLC and etc.

I considered using the IF statements. Some recommended using the toLabel function. Please clarify! Please help!

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

My first though is to use a [map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) for the value replacement like this:

```
trigger MyTrigger on MyObject__c (before insert) {

    Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>{
        '1' => 'Partner',
        '2' => 'LLC',
        '3' => 'Other'
    };

    for (MyObject__c o : Trigger.new) {
        String value = m.get(o.MyField__c);
        if (value != null) o.MyField__c = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using translation workbench to define values stored in the picklist field.

You can show values as different language or set them to a default single language.

If this picklist field is required in some apex coding, you can use toLabel() method to work with the translated values.

For example, You can map 1 as 'partner' in translation workbench and show it to users and if 'partner' value is required in apex logic then use toLabel() method to get 'partner' in the apex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom setting:

```
for(SObject record: Trigger.new)
    if(FieldMap__c.getInstance(record.Field__c) != null)
        record.Field__c = FieldMap__c.getInstance(record.Field__c).Value__c;
```

Or a custom metadata:

```
for(SObject record: Trigger.new)
    try {
        record.Field__c = [SELECT Value__c FROM FieldMap__mdt WHERE Name = :record.Field__c].Value__c;
    } catch(QueryException e) {
        // No match found, go to next
    }
```

*Note:* Custom metadata queries do not count against SOQL limits at all, so this is one of the very rare cases where a query inside a loop is acceptable.

Both options allow you to *change the values* without deploying a new version of your code every time you need to add, remove, or alter a value.